# I am not able to parse JSON data onto an HTML table using Angular JS?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am fairly new to Angular JS . I have a table like this .

```
<tr ng-repeat="job in jobs">

    <td>{{ job.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ job.companyName }}</td>
    <td>{{ job.jobRole }}</td>
    <td>{{ job.salary }}</td>
    <td>{{ job.location }}</td>
    <td>{{ job.jobTitle }}</td>
    <td>{{ job.industry }}</td>
    <td>{{ job.role }}</td>
    <td>{{ job.aboutCompany }}</td>
    <td>{{ job.natureOfWork }}</td>
    <td>{{ job.idealCandidateProfile }}</td>
</tr>
```

and I am trying to fill it up using this .

```
function jobController($scope,$http) {

    var url="http://52.74.160.253:8080/jobs/";
    var LocalData = "data.txt";

    $http.get(LocalData).success( function(response) {
        $scope.jobs = response;
            });

        }
```

Now here is the weird part . I have the JSON data stored both locally and on the server , When i use the locally stored JSON data , it works fine . But when I use the url , I get displayed with an empty table .Both the local and url data are exactly the same .

Comment: Have you checked if the remote URL is returning a header of `application/json`? If not, you might need to run `JSON.parse` on the response.

Comment: Can you check the response in the Network tab of your browser console?

Comment: Are you sure you are sending your request to correct URL? It looks to me as your `url` is not a part of `LocalData` variable.

Comment: See in console. you should get error like XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://52.74.160.253:8080/jobs/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. Please allow cross request in server side